# Django-mptt model serialize with Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-mptt

I have used django-mptt to store categories hierarchy and I need to serialize all category data in below format.

```
{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "FOOD"
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "PIZZA"
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "name": "BURGER"
                }
            ],

        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "ALCOHOL"
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "name": "WINE"
                },
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "name": "VODKA"
                }
            ],

        },
}
```

I'm using django REST framework ModelViewset and serializers.
How to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112302/how-to-serialize-hierarchical-relationship-in-django-rest. take a look at the answer suggested there. note that it is DRF2 specific so it might need to be adjusted for DRF3

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but didn't worked out. So can you help me further?

Comment: I dont know any additional information then what is on that page. sorry

Comment: Check my answer on a similar topic there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65680073/4313735

Answer (score 9):

This response is a year too late, but for the benefit of others, use `RecursiveField` from the [djangorestframework-recursive package](https://github.com/heywbj/django-rest-framework-recursive), which can be installed via:

`pip3 install djangorestframework-recursive`

I was able to do it like so:

```
from rest_framework_recursive.fields import RecursiveField

class MyModelRecursiveSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # your other fields

    children = serializers.ListField(
        read_only=True, source='your_get_children_method', child=RecursiveField()
    )
```

Just be aware that this is potentially expensive, so you might want to only use this for models whose entries do not change that often and cache the results.

Comment: How to deserialize this structure?