# Django rest framework serializer not giving the expected output

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a django model that looks like this:

```
class AcademicProgramsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, acad_program_id, program_title, required_credits):
        return self.get(acad_program_id = acad_program_id, program_title = program_title, required_credits = required_credits)

class AcademicPrograms(models.Model):

    objects = AcademicProgramsManager()
    acad_program_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    acad_program_category = models.ForeignKey(AcademicProgramCategories)
    acad_program_type = models.ForeignKey(AcademicProgramTypes)
    acad_program_code = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    program_title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    required_credits = models.IntegerField()
    min_gpa = models.FloatField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.acad_program_id, self.program_title, self.required_credits)

class StudentAcademicPrograms(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Students)
    academic_program = models.ForeignKey(AcademicPrograms)
    credits_completed = models.IntegerField()
    academic_program_gpa = models.FloatField()
    primary_program = models.BooleanField()
```

This is my serializers.py file:

```
from studentapp.models import AcademicPrograms, AcademicProgramsManager, StudentAcademicPrograms
from rest_framework import serializers

class StudentAcademicProgramsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentAcademicPrograms
    fields = ('credits_completed','academic_program_gpa','primary_program')

class AcademicProgramsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    studentacademicprograms = StudentAcademicProgramsSerializer(many = True)

    class Meta:
        model = AcademicPrograms
        fields = ('acad_program_id','program_title','required_credits','studentacademicprograms')
```

My api.py file looks like this:

```
from studentapp.models import AcademicPrograms, AcademicProgramsManager, StudentAcademicPrograms
from studentapp.serializers import StudentAcademicProgramsSerializer, AcademicProgramsSerializer
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class StudentAcademicProgramsList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        studentacademicprograms = StudentAcademicPrograms.objects.all()
        serialized_studentacademicprograms = StudentAcademicProgramsSerializer(studentacademicprograms, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_studentacademicprograms.data)

class StudentAcademicProgramsDetail(APIView):

    def get_onjects(self, pk):
    try:
        return StudentAcademicPrograms.object.get(pk=pk)
    except StudentAcademicPrograms.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
    studentacademicprogram = self.get_object(pk)
        serialized_studentacademicprogram = StudentAcademicProgramsSerializer(studentacademicprogram)
        return Response(serialized_studentacademicprogram.data)
```

When i call my `StudentAcademicProgramsSerializer` in the urls, i get an output like this:

```
[
    {
        "credits_completed": 32, 
        "academic_program_gpa": 3.7, 
        "primary_program": true
    }, 
    {
        "credits_completed": 32, 
        "academic_program_gpa": 3.4, 
        "primary_program": false
    }
]
```

But i want an output that looks like this:

```
[
{
  "pk": 1,  
  "fields": {
    "academic_program": [
      "acad_program_id": 124, 
      "program_title": "Associate in Arts Degree", 
      "required_credits": 60
    ], 
    "credits_completed": 32, 
    "primary_program": true, 
    "student": 1206, 
    "academic_program_gpa": 3.7
  }
},
{
  "pk": 2,  
  "fields": {
    "academic_program": [
      "acad_program_id": 123, 
      "program_title": "Associate in Sciences Degree", 
      "required_credits": 60
    ], 
    "credits_completed": 32, 
    "primary_program": false, 
    "student": 1206, 
    "academic_program_gpa": 3.4
  }
}
]
```

How do i achieve it?

Comment: won't use `serializers.ModelSerializer` but rather more time-consuming and hand-made `serializers.Serializer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a serializer field in your `StudentAcademicProgramsSerializer`:

```
class AcademicProgramsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AcademicPrograms
        depth = 1


class StudentAcademicProgramsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    academic_program = AcademicProgramsSerializer(source='academic_program')

    class Meta:
        model = StudentAcademicPrograms
        fields = (
            'credits_completed',
            'academic_program_gpa',
            'primary_program', 
            'academic_program'
        )
```

Comment: i am getting a 'AcademicProgramsSerializer' not defined error. Is there anything else missing?

Comment: sorry, you need to move that serializer before this one...i'll update the answer

Comment: no problem, Django REST Framework is really great, have fun with it!

Comment: I ll let you know if run into more trouble ;-)

Comment: hi, can you help me in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354459/angular-js-get-and-set-data-from-rest-framework