# Angular js get and set data from rest framework

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

I have an angular js service written as follows:

```
angular.module('jsonService', ['ngResource'])

    .factory('ProgramsService',function($http) {
        return {
            getItems: function(callback) {
                $http({method:'get', url:'/api/studentacademicprogram/?format=json'}).success(callback);
            }
        };
    })

    .factory('DegreesService', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/static/json/degrees.json')
    })
```

In my app.js, i call this service as follows:

```
app.controller('mycontroller', function(DegreesService, DegreeCategoriesService, DetailsService, ProgramsService, $scope, $modal, $log, $http) {

          ProgramsService.getItems(function(data){
            $scope.programs  = data;
            console.log(data);
          });


          DegreesService.query(function(data){
            $scope.degrees  = data;
            console.log(data);
          });
```

With the help of this code i am able to get json data and reflect it in my front end. But i also would like to add some functionality to update the database that connects to the rest framework when i addchanges in the front end.

How do i do this using $http ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method on your server that accepts HTTP Posts.  Then do something like this:

```
$http.post('/api/studentacademicprogram/', jsonDataToPost).then(function(){
     //post succeeded
}, function() {
    //post failed
});
```

Comment: will i need to deserialize the json data in the rest framework or will it post directly to the database?

Comment: Depends on what framework you're using.  ASP.NET MVC / WebAPI will handle this for you automatically.