# Django Rest Framework: Dynamically return subset of fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

### Problem

As recommended in the blogpost [Best Practices for Designing a Pragmatic RESTful API](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#limiting-fields), I would like to add a `fields` query parameter to a Django Rest Framework based API which enables the user to select only a subset of fields per resource.

### Example

Serializer:

```
class IdentitySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Identity
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'type', 'data')
```

A regular query would return all fields.

`GET /identities/`

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/identities/1/",
    "type": 5,
    "data": "John Doe"
  },
  ...
]
```

A query with the `fields` parameter should only return a subset of the fields:

`GET /identities/?fields=id,data`

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "data": "John Doe"
  },
  ...
]
```

A query with invalid fields should either ignore the invalid fields or throw a client error.

### Goal

Is this possible out of the box somehow? If not, what's the simplest way to implement this? Is there a 3rd party package around that does this already?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

You can override the serializer `__init__` method and set the `fields` attribute dynamically, based on the query params. You can access the `request` object throughout the context, passed to the serializer.

Here is a copy&paste from [Django Rest Framework documentation example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#example) on the matter:

> ```
> from rest_framework import serializers
>
> class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
>     """
>     A ModelSerializer that takes an additional `fields` argument that
>     controls which fields should be displayed.
>     """
>
>     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
>         # Instantiate the superclass normally
>         super(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>
>         fields = self.context['request'].query_params.get('fields')
>         if fields:
>             fields = fields.split(',')
>             # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
>             allowed = set(fields)
>             existing = set(self.fields.keys())
>             for field_name in existing - allowed:
>                 self.fields.pop(field_name)
>
>
> class UserSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
>
>     class Meta:
>         model = User
>         fields = ('url', 'username', 'email')
> ```

Comment: I finally came around to implement this, and it works perfectly! Thanks. I ended up writing a mixin for this, composition is a bit more flexible than subclassing :) https://gist.github.com/dbrgn/4e6fc1fe5922598592d6

Comment: You'll need to change `QUERY_PARAMS` to `query_params` in recent versions of Django, but other than that this works like a charm.

Comment: You probably should check that `requests` exists as a member of `context`. While it does in production it doesn't when running unit tests that create the objects manually.

Comment: Doesn't work for nested resources, and check the comments for the gist above for a few fixes.

Comment: i have made a patch to handle cases where none of values given in fields param doesn't belong to model class for applied serialiser https://gist.github.com/manjitkumar/e6580296d634b0a48487

Comment: I just published this as a package on PyPI! https://github.com/dbrgn/drf-dynamic-fields

Comment: FYI: This example is a verbatim copy of DRF documentation found here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#example It's a bad form to not provide link to original authors

Comment: Can someone elaborate on how this trick could improve performance? Thanks.

Comment: The [DRF documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#example), from which this answer was copied, has been improved since this answer was posted.

Comment: It was returning blank JSON data, then I tried to get the data in to_representation(), there also it is showing blank OrderedDict() to me.

Answer (score 59):

This functionality is available from a [3rd-party package](https://github.com/wimglenn/djangorestframework-queryfields).

```
pip install djangorestframework-queryfields
```

Declare your serializer like this:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from drf_queryfields import QueryFieldsMixin

class MyModelSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin, ModelSerializer):
    ...
```

Then the fields can now be specified (client-side) by using query arguments:

```
GET /identities/?fields=id,data
```

Exclusion filtering is also possible, e.g. to return every field *except* id:

```
GET /identities/?fields!=id
```

*disclaimer:*  I'm the author/maintainer.

Comment: Hi. What is the difference between this and https://github.com/dbrgn/drf-dynamic-fields (as linked in the comments of the chosen answer)?

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at that implementation, and it looks like it's the same basic idea.  But the `dbrgn` implementation has some differences: 1. doesn't support exclude with `fields!=key1,key2`.  2. also modifies serializers outside of GET request context, which can and will break some PUT/POST requests.  3. does not accumulate fields with e.g. `fields=key1&fields=key2`, which is a nice-to-have for ajax apps.  It also has zero test coverage, which is somewhat unusual in OSS.

Comment: @wim Which versions of DRF and Django does your library support? I didn't find anything in the docs.

Comment: Django 1.7-1.11+, basically any configuration that DRF supports. This comment might go out of date, so check the [test matrix for the CI, here](https://github.com/wimglenn/djangorestframework-queryfields/blob/master/.travis.yml).

Comment: Works great for me: Django==2.2.7, djangorestframework==3.10.3, djangorestframework-queryfields==1.0.0

Comment: this work very well when the api returns list but when it return single object like `/identities/1/?fields=id,data it don't work?` any ideas?

Comment: @alial-karaawi It certainly does work on the detail response and [there are tests for that](https://github.com/wimglenn/djangorestframework-queryfields/blob/b0aed3eb51625b20d187aa2ca1ec5a2982b979e2/tests/test_userfields_with_modelserializer.py#L57-L64). Perhaps you should post a question with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 8):

## **serializers.py**

```
class DynamicFieldsSerializerMixin(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super(DynamicFieldsSerializerMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields.keys())
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)


class UserSerializer(DynamicFieldsSerializerMixin, serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')


    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name']
        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

## **views.py**

```
class DynamicFieldsViewMixin(object):

 def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):

    serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()

    fields = None
    if self.request.method == 'GET':
        query_fields = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get("fields", None)

        if query_fields:
            fields = tuple(query_fields.split(','))


    kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
    kwargs['fields'] = fields

    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)



class UserList(DynamicFieldsViewMixin, ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Answer (score 4):

## Configure a new pagination serializer class

```
from rest_framework import pagination, serializers

class DynamicFieldsPaginationSerializer(pagination.BasePaginationSerializer):
    """
    A dynamic fields implementation of a pagination serializer.
    """
    count = serializers.Field(source='paginator.count')
    next = pagination.NextPageField(source='*')
    previous = pagination.PreviousPageField(source='*')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Override init to add in the object serializer field on-the-fly.
        """
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)
        super(pagination.BasePaginationSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        results_field = self.results_field
        object_serializer = self.opts.object_serializer_class

        if 'context' in kwargs:
            context_kwarg = {'context': kwargs['context']}
        else:
            context_kwarg = {}

        if fields:
            context_kwarg.update({'fields': fields})

        self.fields[results_field] = object_serializer(source='object_list',
                                                       many=True,
                                                       **context_kwarg)


# Set the pagination serializer setting
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # [...]
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_SERIALIZER_CLASS': 'DynamicFieldsPaginationSerializer',
}
```

## Make dynamic serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A ModelSerializer that takes an additional `fields` argument that
    controls which fields should be displayed.

    See:
        http://tomchristie.github.io/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/serializers
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields:
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields.keys())
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
# Use it
class MyPonySerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    # [...]
```

## Last, use a homemage mixin for your APIViews

```
class DynamicFields(object):
    """A mixins that allows the query builder to display certain fields"""

    def get_fields_to_display(self):
        fields = self.request.GET.get('fields', None)
        return fields.split(',') if fields else None

    def get_serializer(self, instance=None, data=None, files=None, many=False,
                       partial=False, allow_add_remove=False):
        """
        Return the serializer instance that should be used for validating and
        deserializing input, and for serializing output.
        """
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        context = self.get_serializer_context()
        fields = self.get_fields_to_display()
        return serializer_class(instance, data=data, files=files,
                                many=many, partial=partial,
                                allow_add_remove=allow_add_remove,
                                context=context, fields=fields)

    def get_pagination_serializer(self, page):
        """
        Return a serializer instance to use with paginated data.
        """
        class SerializerClass(self.pagination_serializer_class):
            class Meta:
                object_serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()

        pagination_serializer_class = SerializerClass
        context = self.get_serializer_context()
        fields = self.get_fields_to_display()
        return pagination_serializer_class(instance=page, context=context, fields=fields)

class MyPonyList(DynamicFields, generics.ListAPIView):
    # [...]
```

## Request

Now, when you request a resource, you can add a parameter `fields` to show only specified fields in url.
`/?fields=field1,field2`

You can find a reminder here : https://gist.github.com/Kmaschta/e28cf21fb3f0b90c597a

Answer (score 4):

You could try [Dynamic REST](https://dynamic-rest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which has support for dynamic fields (inclusion, exclusion), embedded / sideloaded objects, filtering, ordering, pagination, and more.

Answer (score 4):

If you want something flexible like GraphQL, you can use [django-restql](https://github.com/yezyilomo/django-restql). It supports nested data (both flat and iterable).

**Example**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django_restql.mixins import DynamicFieldsMixin

class UserSerializer(DynamicFieldsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'groups')
```

A regular request returns all fields.

`GET /users`

```
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "yezyilomo",
        "email": "yezileliilomo@hotmail.com",
        "groups": [1,2]
      },
      ...
    ]
```

A request with the `query` parameter on the other hand returns only a subset of
the fields:

`GET /users/?query={id, username}`

```
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "yezyilomo"
      },
      ...
    ]
```

With **django-restql** you can access nested fields of any level. E.g

`GET /users/?query={id, username, date_joined{year}}`

```
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "yezyilomo",
        "date_joined": {
            "year": 2018
        }
      },
      ...
    ]
```

For iterable nested fields, E.g groups on users.

`GET /users/?query={id, username, groups{id, name}}`

```
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "yezyilomo",
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Auth_User"
            }
        ]
      },
      ...
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Such functionality we've provided in [drf_tweaks / control-over-serialized-fields](https://github.com/ArabellaTech/drf_tweaks#control-over-serialized-fields).

If you use our serializers, all you need is to pass `?fields=x,y,z` parameter in the query.

Answer (score 2):

For nested data, I am using Django Rest Framework with the package recommended in the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#drf-flexfields), [drf-flexfields](https://github.com/rsinger86/drf-flex-fields)

This allows you to restrict the fields returned on both the parent and child objects. The instructions in the readme are good, just a few things to watch out for:

The URL seems to need the / like this '/person/?expand=country&fields=id,name,country' instead of as written in the readme '/person?expand=country&fields=id,name,country'

The naming of the nested object and its related name need to be completely consistent, which isn't required otherwise.

If you have 'many' e.g. a country can have many states, you'll need to set 'many': True in the Serializer as described in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested at the [DRF-Documentation][1] worked for me, however when I called the serializer from the View with:

```
class SomeView(ListAPIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        qry=table.objects.filter(column_value=self.kwargs['urlparameter'])
        fields=['DBcol1','DBcol2','DBcol3']    
        serializer=SomeSerializer(qry,many=True,fields=fields)
```

I had to add `many=True`, otherwise it was not working.

```
  [1]: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#example
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to make use of GraphWrap: https://github.com/PaulGilmartin/graph_wrap

By adding /graphql to your urlpatterns, you add layer your REST API with a fully compliant GraphQL queryable API.