# Django serializer return partial data

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

My code for receiving data and then returning the response is:

```
serializer = VideoSerializer(data=data, partial=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
    return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Here if the serializer is valid I want to **return partial data** from the serializer(after removing some fields).

It could be done if I create another serializer object and pass fields tuple to it as given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23674297/1694699 but that would mean another database call also I will have to query for the id to pass it to the new serializer object.

Is their any better approach?

Comment: May be `write_only` field parameter helps?

Comment: I am not sure I get the problem. Is it not working by removing the fields from `serializer.validated_data` ? (or a copy of it). BTW `partial` is for [updates](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates), not for creating a new instance, right?

Comment: @user2172884 got it working using `write_only` parameter, thanks.