# Is it possible to set permission per field?

Tags: django, rest, security, permissions, django-rest-framework

I am building a rest api application with django-rest-framework. I came to the phase where I want to put in place some security.
I have a `user` ressources with the following fields `firstname, lastname, dateofbirth` (just to say a few). So in my user object they are private fields and fields which can be public.
Is there a way to limit the out put fields in the response base on the `drf Permission`, or if no what would the best practise in genera ?

for example :
When the user with the id 1 use : `api/user/1` he gets:

`{ 
   "id": "1", 
   "firstname":"john",
   "lastname":"Smith", 
   "dateofbirth":"2015-11-11"
}`

When the user with the id 2 use : `api/user/1` he gets:

`{ 
   "id": "1",
   "firstname":"john",
   "lastname":"Smith"
 }`

which only says that the `dateofbirth` is a private fie

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by overriding the **init** method in your user serializer like:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'pk' in kwargs:
            if not self.context['request'].user.id == kwargs['pk']:
                self.fields.pop('dateofbirth')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'dateofbirth')
```

you can also refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643204/django-rest-framework-dynamically-return-subset-of-fields)

Comment: Thank you, sounds like a start. But I think that i rather create 2 serializers, and play with a `get_serializer` method on the api view.