# DRF - `write_only=True` displays in response schema

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I'm using [drf-yasg](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg) to document my APIs. However, I'm running into a problem

I've a serializer in which one of the fields is set to `write_only=True`.

```
class XYZSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = serializers.BooleanField(default=True, write_only=True)

    class Meta:

        model = XYZ
        fields = ('id', 'status')
```

When generating the swagger docs, field `status` still shows in the Response fields. Technically, it should not.

How to correct this?

Comment: You should've add link to issue that *probably you* opened: [*A field having `write_only=True` displays in response schema.*](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/165)

Answer (score 2):

Shortly:
Developers of drf-yasg have [answered](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/70) about it. Problem in OpenAPI 2.0 specification and you could use https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular (it support OpenAPI 3.0) instead of drf-yasg.

You could in create special serializer for decorator only

```
@swagger_auto_schema(responses={200: CustomResponseSerializer()})
```

or make your serilializer's fields dynamic([Django Rest Framework: Dynamically return subset of fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643204/django-rest-framework-dynamically-return-subset-of-fields)) and decorate action in viewset like this

```
@swagger_auto_schema(responses={200: YourSerializer(fields=['some_field_name', 'another_...')})
```

Also in https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/70 you could find another way from https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/70#issuecomment-698288806

Comment: Confirmation here. I just dropped drf-yasg for drf-spectacular and it works!