# Get only one filed from a nested serializer

Tags: django

Her it is my django serializer:

```
class ShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rest = RestSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = RestaurantLike
        fields = ('id', 'created', 'updated', 'rest')
```

This will wrap whole RestSerializer inside ShopSerializer on response.
How can I get only one or two fields from RestSerializer instead of having all the fields inside ShopSerializer?

Get only two field of RestSerializer instead of whole RestSerializer

Comment: Use different serializer for the field?

Comment: Any cleaner way?

Comment: This can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/23674297/11544538

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have limited amount of fields from RestSerializer, then you can simply limit it in the fields:

```
class RestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = ('id', 'name', ...)
```

If you want just want field, lets say the primary key or Slug, then you can use [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) or [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) for that. For example:

```
class ShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rest = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='name'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = RestaurantLike
        fields = ('id', 'created', 'updated', 'rest')
```