# How to dynamically remove fields from serializer output

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm developing an API with Django Rest framework, and I would like to dynamically remove the fields from a serializer. The problem is that I need to remove them depending on the value of another field. How could I do that?
I have a serializer like:

```
class DynamicSerliazer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    title = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    elements = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DynamicSerliazer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.fields and is_mobile_platform(self.context.get('request', None)) and "url" in self.fields:
            self.fields.pop("url")
```

As you can see, I'm already removing the field "url" depending whether the request has been done from a mobile platform. But, I would like to remove the "elements" field depending on the "type" value. How should I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You **can [customize the serialization behavior](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior) by overriding the `to_representation()` method** in your serializer.

```
class DynamicSerliazer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        # get the original representation
        ret = super(DynamicSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)

        # remove 'url' field if mobile request
        if is_mobile_platform(self.context.get('request', None)):
            ret.pop('url')

        # here write the logic to check whether `elements` field is to be removed 
        # pop 'elements' from 'ret' if condition is True

        # return the modified representation
        return ret
```

Answer (score 7):

You can create multiple serializers and choose the proper one in view

```
class IndexView(APIView):
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.GET['flag']:
            return SerializerA
        return SerializerB
```

use inheritance to make serializers DRY.

Comment: As of today, this works if you use `get_serializer_class` instead of `get_serializer`.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was somewhat similar to yours and I solved it with inheritance.

```
class StaticSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = StaticModel
        fields = (
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'username',
            'email'
        )


class DynamicSerializer(StaticSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = StaticModel
        fields = (
            'first_name',
        )
```

Comment: This is nice, but not dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution (ViewSet mixin)

I have solved this problem by writing my own ViewSet mixin. It provides quite easy and DRY way to override serializers depending on request action.

```
class ActionBasedSerializerClassMixin(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        attr_name = f'{self.action}_serializer_class'
        if hasattr(self, attr_name):
            serializer_class = getattr(self, attr_name)
            self.serializer_class = serializer_class
        return super().get_serializer_class()
```

### Usage

To use this mixin inherit from it at your viewset (It must be before ModelViewSet parent).
The default serializer is always used as fallback
To use different serializer on **list** action just set attribute `list_serializer_class` at your viewset:

```
    class MyViewSet(ViewSet):
        serializer_class = MySerializer
        list_serializer_class = MyListSerializer
```

With this code you will have MyListSerializer when action is 'list' and MySerializer for all other actions.
The same patterns works for all other action types: list, create, retrieve, update, partial_update, destroy.
You just need to append _serializer_class to get desired attribute name.

**How serailizers should look like**

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    some_reverse_rel = MyOtherSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'foo', 'bar', 'some_reverse_rel']

class MyListSerailizer(MySerializer):  # Note that we inherit from previous serializer
    some_reverse_rel = None  # Getting rid of reverse relationship

    class Meta(MySerializer.Meta):
        fields = ['foo', 'bar', 'field1']
```