# Serialize queryset based on individual field values using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

**Goal**

If an object has `revealed=true` it serializes into:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "info":"top secret info",
   "revealed":true
}
```

If an object has `revealed=false` the `info` field is `null`:

```
{
   "id":2,
   "info":null,
   "revealed":false
}
```

So for a queryset of objects:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "info":"top secret info 1",
      "revealed":true
   },
   {
       "id":2,
       "info":null,
       "revealed":false
   },
   {  
      "id":3,
      "info":"top secret info 3",
      "revealed":true
   }
]
```

**Is it possible to achieve this inside of a Django Rest Framework Model Serializer class?**

```
class InfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Info
        fields = ('id', 'info', 'revealed')
```

**Background**

The [DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#advanced-serializer-usage) discuss some advanced serializer usage, and [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37985581/how-to-dynamically-remove-fields-from-serializer-output) dives into an example. However it doesn't seem to cover this particular issue.

**Ideas**

A hacky solution would be to iterate over the serialized data afterwards, and remove the `info` field for every object that has `revealed=false`. However 1) it involves an extra loop and 2) would need to be implemented everywhere the data is serialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you make the `info` field appear on all records, but leave it null when `revealed` is false. If that's acceptable, you should be able to make it happen with a [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

Alternatively, you could add a `revealed_info` attribute to the model class, and expose that through the serializer.

```
@property
def revealed_info(self):
    return self.info if self.revealed else None
```

Comment: Ah yes, SerializerMethodField should be perfect. Thank you!