# Django REST Framework Extension recursive nested urls

Tags: python, django, drf-extensions, nested-urls

I want to create URLs for CMS portion of project I have following models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)

class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='pages')
```

I want the following URL structure for my categories

```
/categories/{parent category}/
/categories/{parent category}/{child category}/.../{child category}/pages/
```

How would I accomplish this with DRF-Extensions or any other plugin?

Comment: why you need recursive, if your categories has unique id?

Comment: Recursive because, I am planning on creating variable number of child categories. I don't know how to set this behavior with DRF-Extension Nested Routers (Pretty new to Django). And I don't want to explicitly set views and routes for each child category.

Comment: but you don need the recursive route to get category from url, it is enough only id

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package for recursive serialization under DRF.

https://github.com/heywbj/django-rest-framework-recursive

There is an earlier discussion on stackoverflow:
[Django rest framework nested self-referential objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376894/django-rest-framework-nested-self-referential-objects/27236783)