# Lack of data with serialization model with ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, manytomanyfield

Here's are examples I have:

**models.py:**

```
class Example(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    description = models.CharField(...)

class Foo(models.Model):
    example = models.ManyToManyField(Example)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

**views.py:**

```
...
serialized_data = [FooSerializer(foo).data for foo in Foo.objects.all().get]
```

In output, I receive only `Example`'s IDs, but is there any way I could get title and description fields also (details of m2mfield)? As I understand, `Foo.objects.all().get` simply doesn't contain this data, but maybe I could somehow get it and use it?
I could also rebuild models if needed, but currently I use m2mf because of needs to contain multiple objects as related to this model data.

**update**

**models.py**:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    ts = models.BigIntegerField(editable=False)

class Foo(Event):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)
    example = *...(remains to be the same)*
    foos = models.ForeignKey('self', **somemore** null=True)
```

**serializers.py**:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        result = {'ts': instance.ts}
        if isinstance(instance, Foo):
            result['foo'] = FooSerializer(instance).data
        return result

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username')

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   # user = UserSerializer(read_only=True) # with this I have an error: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 'username' on #serializer 'UserSerializer'

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`depth`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) attribute to achieve desired output.

> The default **ModelSerializer** uses primary keys for relationships, but
>   you can also easily generate nested representations using the **depth**
>   option.The depth option should be set to an integer value that
>   **indicates the depth of relationships that should be traversed before
>   reverting to a flat representation**.

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

Apart from the answer, I would like to change your `views.py` code, cause it seems like very bad :(. Do it on **DRF Way** as

```
serialized_data = FooSerializer(Foo.objects.all(), many=True).data<br>
```

**Example View**

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet


class FooViewset(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
```

**UPDATE-1**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ('password',) # add fields that are need to be excluded 


class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

**`depth = 1`** will serializer **all** fields in the `model`, (It's  same as setting the `fields=='__all__'` in Meta class of serializer)
**UPDATE-2**

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        real_data = super().to_representation(instance).copy()
        # DO YOUR EXTRA CHECKS
        child = UserSerializer(instance.child_foo).data
        if child:
            real_data.update({"child_data": child})
        # After your checks, add it to "real_data"
        return real_data
```

and I assumed I have a `Foo` model as

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    example = models.ManyToManyField(Example)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    child_foo = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: I have User's model ForeignKey in Foo and by adding depth it shows me password and other fields.
And at some point I can't serialize users model because it says `AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 'username' on serializer 'UserSerializer'`
Same happens for manytomanyfields in model :(

Comment: If you wish to **exclude** some fields, you have to define a separate serializer, That is a **nested serializer**

Comment: If you update your question with **Actual Code** and  **relevant relationship**, I could help you more, That is, user model/abstract user model, userserailzer l etc

Comment: My user is inherited from abstract user model, theres nothing special. It contains pwd, username and id. And it would be enough if I had shown only id and username. **Updated topic, hope it helps**

Comment: In fact, I just do not understand why, by adding depth, I see much more data than those with which a serializer can work

Comment: Can you also help with using https://stackoverflow.com/a/29651543/9048369 solution in `to_representation` at `EventSerializer`? I have recursive field but `RecursiveField().to_representation(instance.recursive)` says `TypeError: NoneType takes no arguments` at line `serializer = serializer_class(value, many=self._recurse_many, context=self.context)`

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. Which field did you make as `self-referencing FK`, (in which model)?

Comment: in `Foo` I've added `foos = models.ForeignKey('self', **somemore** null=True)`

Comment: You don't want to override `to_representaon()` or anything. Just use `depth=2` instead of `depth=1` ;)

Comment: Yes but by overriding to_representation() I can filter null fields and use other logic

Answer (score 1):

In your serializer add depth = 1. Example where 'users' is the related field:

```
FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('id', 'account_name', 'users', 'created')
        depth = 1
```