# Serialize m2mfield('self')

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this model in `models.py`:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

How can I serialize it?
I was using one of solutions from this topic: [Django rest framework nested self-referential objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376894/django-rest-framework-nested-self-referential-objects) But none of them working with `M2M`, either causes in infinity cycle of serialization. Solution where I'm using a row of serializers works good except it's limited by copy&paste (sounds really sad :) )

Generic `model` mostly looks like a comment's tree. I hope such a problem was already solved before but haven't found how yet.

Comment: Typically in that case the serializer returns a list of *ids*, not the serialization of these objects. Since if an object refers to itself, it will indeed lead to infinite recursion.

Comment: So i need to iterate through each instance of m2m field?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will get a *straight solution* to this, so try this

```
class FooBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Foo


class FooSerializer(FooBaseSerializer):
    bar = FooBaseSerializer(many=True)
```

Comment: it repeats values each second cycle

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: As a Software Engineer, I love to use Architectures and I have deeply worked on Layered Approach for Development so I am gonna be Answering it with Respect to Tiers.

I would suggest the use of a Bridge Table for M2M relationships to Normalize Stuff. Anyhow serializing many of the Items would require to

```
serializer = SerializerNameGoesHere(AllFilteredObjectsfromModel, many=True)
```

would serializer m2m.
Here's an Example in Layered Approach!

As i understood the Issue, Here's the Solution

models.py

```
class Member(models.Model):
    member_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    member_name = models.CharField(max_length = 

class Group(models.Model):
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    fk_member_id = models.ForeignKey('Member', models.DO_NOTHING, 
                             db_column='fk_member_id', blank=True, null=True)

class Membership(models.Model):
    membershipid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fk_group_id = models.ForeignKey('Group', models.DO_NOTHING, 
                             db_column='fk_member_id', blank=True, null=True)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

serializers.py

```
import serializer

class AllSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    group_id = serializer.IntegerField()
    group_name = serializer.CharField(max_length = 20)
    join_date = serializer.DateTimeField()
```

CustomModels.py

```
imports...

    class AllDataModel():
        group_id = ""
        group_name = ""
        join_date = ""
```

BusinessLogic.py

```
imports ....
class getdata(memberid):
    alldataDict = {}
    dto = []
    Member = models.Members.objects.get(member_id=memberid) #or use filter for Name
    alldataDict["MemberId"] = Member.member_id
    alldataDict["MemberName"] = Member.member_name
    Groups = models.Group.objects.filter(fk_member_id=Member)
    for item in Groups:
        Custommodel = CustomModels.AllDataModel()
        Custommodel.group_id = item.group_id
        Custommodel.group_name = item.group_name
        Membership = models.Membership.objects.get(fk_group_id=item.group_id)
        Custommodel.join_date = Membership.join_date
        dto.append(Custommodel)
    serializer = AllSerializer(dto,many=True)
    alldataDict.update(serializer.data)
    return alldataDict
```

Comment: Thanks for well-explained solution but it wouldn't work in my case. My refinement about "mostly like comment tree"  probably lacks one detail. For simple `ForeignKey('self')`-like field there are no problems with serializers, but if each `comment` can contain sub-comments, the depth makes an access limited to some of levels . 
Unfortunately, I couldn't make it work with overriding drf framework for this case and iterations through cycles didnt work any good

Comment: I saw Your Other Post with the Archietecture Explained and Loved it. Simple and Organized Code!