# Django rest framework save parent records on same model

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have model like this:

```
class Company(models.Model):
"""Company model"""
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
active = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
type = models.JSONField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
alias = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
telecom = models.JSONField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
part_of = models.ForeignKey("company.Company", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,
                            blank=True, related_name="parent")
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False, null=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False, null=True)
deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'organizations'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

And serializer:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Company
    fields = '__all__'
    read_only_fields = ("id",)
    part_of = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Company.objects.all())

def create(self, validated_data):

    part_of = validated_data.pop("part_of")

    if part_of:
        company_id = Company.objects.create(**part_of)
        validated_data['part_of'] = company_id

    company = Company.objects.create(**validated_data)
    return company
```

And view:

```
class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    serializer_class = serializers.CompanySerializer
    queryset = Company.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

It is working fine with empty value of **"part_of":""**, but doesn't work while I pass value for part_of. part_of is basically a parent company which I am trying to create. so my expectation is create a company(part_of) first, get it's id and make that id as foreign key for another company.
Anyone implemented similar to this? Or what I am doing wrong here, suggestions, help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The error I am getting is:

```
{
"part_of": [
    "“{ 'name': 'Parent of Organization', 'telecom': [{'system': 'phone', 'value': '677-7777'}, {'system': 'email', 'value': 'customerservice@abc.com'}], 'address': [{'line': ['3300 Washtenaw Avenue, Suite 227'], 'city': 'Amherst', 'state': 'MA', 'postalCode': '01002', 'country': 'USA'}]}” is not a valid UUID."
]
```

}

Comment: Since `part_of` field has been declared as `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, it's expecting a primary key and not the company object. In this case you'll need to use `CompanySerializer` for `part_of` as well

Comment: @BrianDestura, Can I call same serializer inside it like this?

    `class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Company
    fields = '__all__'
    read_only_fields = ("id",)
    part_of = CompanySerializer(many=false, readonly=false)`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating a new serializer for parent company as mentioned in this [post](http://#%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376894/django-rest-framework-nested-self-referential-objects#answer-13377226):

```
class ParentCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'


class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializers for Company objects"""
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ("id", )

    part_of = ParentCompanySerializer(many=False, read_only=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        part_of = validated_data.pop('part_of') if 'part_of' in validated_data else None
        if part_of:
            company_id = Company.objects.create(**part_of)
            validated_data['part_of'] = company_id
        
company = Company.objects.create(**validated_data)
       return company
```

Hope this will help someone who stuck in similar situation like me.

Answer (score 0):

I think to make a model also a child os same model we have to do something like  -

```
part_of = models.ForeignKey("self")
```

and create method should be something like -

```
def create(self, validated_data): 
    part_of = validated_data.pop("part_of") ## check if part_of exist in validated data then do this step.
    company_id = Company.objects.create(validated_data) ##pop removed part_of data from validated_data so pass validated data here

    if part_of:
        company = Company.objects.create(part_of = company_id, **part_of)
    return company
```

Well customize it according to your needs.

Comment: The idea is to create part_of data as a parent company and other as a child. I tried this but give me error:    

    def create(self, validated_data):
            part_of = validated_data.pop("part_of")
            company_id = Company.objects.create(**part_of)
    
            if part_of:
                company = Company.objects.create(part_of=company_id, **validated_data)
            return company

**Error: Cannot assign "''": "Company.part_of" must be a "Company" instance.**

Comment: Ok so primaryRelatedKey by default is read-write [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield). and as you have included it in your serializers it is expecting a value of part_of (Company" instance) everytime a  new company is created. make changes to be this as read only . You code seems good it showld work.

Comment: I tried, but its not working. There is no error but not creating part_of(parent) one, other one is being created.

Comment: CHECK THE id of parent in other one. since you are first creating the parent and then passing its id. so check whether other one has parent  id or not.

Comment: I believe parent is getting created and because you have **part_of = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Company.objects.all())** you are not able to see.

Comment: No its not created, I checked in the DB.