# Django Recursive Foreign Key for Serializer Getting not iterable errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I followed a lot of answers regarding my questions, I tried all solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376894/django-rest-framework-nested-self-referential-objects)

Basically scenario is almost same I wanted recursive query in my serializer.
Firstly I want to show my models

```
class Policy(TimeStampedModel):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='policies', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', editable=True, slugify_function=slugify)
```

and I have Foreign Key from `Policy` to `PolicyCondition`
here is policy condition model.

```
class PolicyCondition(TimeStampedModel):
    policy = models.ForeignKey(Policy, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', editable=True, slugify_function=slugify,null=True)

    text = models.TextField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='children'
    )
```

On serializer I am fetching all my data from policy model. Here is my serializer.

```
class PolicyListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    conditions = PolicyConditionSerializer(source='policycondition_set', many=True)



 class Meta:
        model = Policy
        fields = ['conditions']
```

Here is my policy condition serializer

```
class PolicyConditionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = PolicyCondition
        fields = [
            'id',
            'policy',
            'name',
            'text',
            'slug',
            'parent'
        ]

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        self.fields['parent'] = PolicyConditionSerializer(read_only=True)
        return super(PolicyConditionSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
```

I am getting error as
`PolicyCondition' object is not iterable` any soluton what I am missing here.

Comment: You missed data: PolicyConditionSerializer(read_only=True).data

Comment: I am getting new error now `'ReturnDict' object has no attribute 'bind'`

Comment: You can see two options in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change serializer class like this:

```
class PolicyConditionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parent = PolicyConditionSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = PolicyCondition
        fields = [
            'id',
            'policy',
            'name',
            'text',
            'slug',
            'parent'
        ]
```

or edit to_representation:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super(PolicyConditionSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    data['parent'] = PolicyConditionSerializer(read_only=True).data
    return data
```

Comment: any way where i can remove repeated parent

Comment: actullay the solution is still as not per required